# Using nonce in Settings API - WordPress plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress, nonce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am a newbie in plugin development and I'm stuck with nonces. I'm creating my first plugin but I can't figure out how to implement and verify nonce in my form.

I find a couple of tutorials and I have checked official docs, but still, I have an issue with this.

This is my class in a short for the admin part:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Dashboard' ) ) {

    class Dashboard {
        public function __construct() {
            add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'agy_dashboard'));
            add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'agy_register_settings'));
        }

        public function agy_dashboard() {
            add_submenu_page(
                'tools.php',
                __( 'Agy', 'agy' ),
                __( 'Agy', 'agy' ),
                'manage_options',
                'agy-dashboard',
                array( $this, 'agy_dashboard_page' )
            );
        }

        public function agy_dashboard_page() {
            ?>
            <div id="agy-wrap" class="wrap">
                <form action="options.php" method="post">
                    <?php

                    do_settings_sections( 'agy_settings_section_tab1' );

                    submit_button(
                        __( 'Save Changes', 'agy' ),
                        '',
                        'agy_save_changes_btn',
                        true,
                        array( 'id' => 'agy-save-changes-btn' )
                    );
                    ?>

                </form>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        public function agy_register_settings() {
            register_setting(
                'agy_settings_fields',
                'agy_settings_fields',
                'agy_sanitize_callback'
            );

            // Adding sections
            add_settings_section(
                'agy_section_id',
                __( 'General', 'agy' ),
                array( $this, 'agy_settings_section_callback' ),
                'agy_settings_section_tab1'
            );

            add_settings_field(
                'agy_section_id_enabled_disabled',
                __( 'Enable / Disable', 'agy' ),
                array( $this, 'agy_section_id_enabled_disabled' ),
                'agy_settings_section_tab1',
                'agy_section_id'
            );
        }

        public function agy_settings_section_tab3_callback() {
            _e( 'Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim.', 'agy' );
        }

        public function agy_section_id_enabled_disabled() {
            echo '<label class="agy-switch" for="agy-enabled-disabled"><input type="checkbox" id="agy-enabled-disabled"
            class="agy-switch-input" name="agy_settings_fields[enabled_disabled]"
            value="1" ' . $this->option_check_radio_btn( 'enabled_disabled' ) . '>
            <span class="agy-slider agy-round"></span></label>';
        }
    }
    new Dashboard();
}
```

I tried to set `wp_nonce_field('agy_dashboard_save')` inside the `<form>` and outside the form I tried with this:

```
if (isset($_POST['agy_save_changes_btn'])) {
    check_admin_referer( 'agy_dashboard_save' );
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's a proper way to implement and verify nonce.

Thanks